# CMD Inserts A bad char Using powercfg

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

hi Im running a batch file that craetes a log, it was going fine, but something is wrong with Windows and it becomes stupid.

There is a pic: of the error
[image]

I tried: Using an escape char ^, I tried saving my file using ANSI charactares, and unicode, using notepad++.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try typing the `-` again yourself. I suspect you're using a unicode character "figure dash" (that's not the same as the `-` but `‒`) or something. They look similar but are different characters. If you over-type the `-` yourself and save as ansi it should be ok.

Comment: Yes, about - char you were fine, but what about > char... than 1 before the > char, is hurting de command.

Comment: Try the same thing...delete the character immediately before the `>` and type a space.

Comment: Thanks, Something is wrong with my windows installation, another engineer runs the same batch file an he got the report...